# Called object is not a function or a function pointer

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

I have the following code.

```
typedef pid_t (*getpidType)(void);

pid_t getpid(void)
{
    printf("Hello, getpid!\n");
    getpidType* f = (getpidType*)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getpid");
    return f(); // <-- Problem here
}
```

The compiler complains that `called object ‘f’ is not a function`. What is going on here? Haven't I declared and used the function pointer **f** in a correct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getpidType` is already a pointer, so drop the `*`:

```
getpidType f = (getpidType)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getpid");
```

(Even better, drop the explicit cast as well:

```
getpidType f = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getpid");
```

Since `dlsym` returns `void*` and `void*` is implicitly convertible to any other pointer type, the cast is not needed. It may even hide bugs.)

Comment: Yes you are right void* is convertible to any type in C, but not in C++, so for portability I keep it.

Comment: @user1018562, when you write in C, write in C! There is no portability issue. You can link C-compiled and C++-compiled files together.

Comment: @user1018562: that's only an issue when you want to write in the subset of C and C++, which is an art form in itself and requires intimate knowledge of both languages. Shahbaz is right, compatibility at link time is a lot easier to establish.